# Remove a dynamically added element without using on()

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have a page built in meteor js and i have no access to `on()`. I have this `div`

```
<div class="row crud">

</div
```

which i am adding elements to it like this

```
$( ".crud" ).append('<div class="aor"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><label>'+v+'    <i class="icon-cancel-square2"></i> </label><input type="text" name="results_'+v+'" class="form-control" placeholder="'+v+'"></div></div></div>');
```

All form elements have a delete button of the class `.icon-cancel-square2`

```
'click .icon-cancel-square2': function(){
    alert('that connected');
    $(this).closest(".form-group").remove();
},
```

The alert connects but cannot remove. How can i remove an element without necessarily using on?.

Comment: If you can't use the `on()` method, are you able to use the native [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead?

Comment: I feel like the "I have no access to on()" needs some explanation to make it easier to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Meteorjs the context of the event is actually the data context of the template so it is the `this` causing your problems here.

Try:

`'click .icon-cancel-square2': function(event, template){
    alert('that connected');
    event.target.closest('.form-group').remove();
},`